# How to Full Text Search - Extension "tsvector" is not supported by Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, full-text-search, amazon-rds, tsvector

I'm using Postgres v12.8 on AWS RDS. Installng TSVECTOR I get the error:

> SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: Extension "tsvector" is not supported by Amazon RDS
> Detail: Installing the extension "tsvector" failed, because it is not on the list of extensions supported by Amazon RDS.
> Hint: Amazon RDS allows users with rds_superuser role to install supported extensions. See: SHOW rds.extensions;

[image]

The reason is because AWS RDS Postgres doesn't support the Extension:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions

And it doesn't look like AWS RDS are going to add it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111481/9328

So I have two questions,

1. Was TSVECTOR supported in the past in v9 (as per [On AWS RDS Postgres, how to have dictionaries and unaccented full-text search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40032685/495455))?
   If that's the case what are these people doing now as AWS have warned for over a year they would automatically upgrade v9 Postgres db's on the 18th Jan 2022?
2. What can I use to achieve Full Text Search in Postgres RDS? I don't want to have to spin up an EC2 or a Container for access to install TSVECTOR, surely there must be an alternative?

---

The documentation says RDS Postgres supports Full Text Search: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/features/

> Full Text Search Dictionaries – PostgreSQL supports Full Text Searching that provides the capability to identify natural-language documents that satisfy a query, and optionally to sort them by relevance to the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps Amazon did something strange, but in PostgreSQL there is no `tsvector` extension. `tsvector` is a built-in data type, and you don't have to install any extensions to use full-text search.

Comment: I feel pretty silly right now, the `TSVECTOR` wasn't colour highlighted as a recognised type!